# Vuetify custom styling of vuetify components like v-textarea with css

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

How can I target the underlying html textarea of a vuetify v-textarea with css? In my case I want to change the line-height, font-family, color and more of the v-textarea. It doesn't work like this:

```
<v-textarea class="custom-textarea"></v-textarea>

.custom-textarea {
  line-height: 1;
  color: red;
}
```

I also tried several other selectors like `v-textarea`, `.v-textarea`, `v-text-field__slot` but none of these worked either. What is the right selector for the textarea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to override a deep element, you need to access the element through deep selectors like

`::v-deep .v-textarea textarea`

[More information about deep selectors](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.custom-textarea textarea {
  line-height: 1;
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Set `id` prop of text-area and apply css style by id.

```html
<v-textarea id="input-7-2"></v-textarea>
```

```css
#input-7-2 {
  color:white;
  background-color: green;
  line-height:1;
}
```

[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/nileshpatel17/pen/rNMYMvy)